# Reproduce-able: Lighthouse returned error: NO_FCP

Tags: pagespeed

My friend's site is http://www.mysalonrules.net

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=mysalonrules.net%2F

It's a simple site, loads fine for me from any browser. I'm trying to see if I can optimize her loading speed but every attempt at checking through pagespeed results in the above error. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I believe (after answering similar questions and some testing) that this is caused by Lighthouse attempting to run a test for HTTPS.

Your site is hosted on a server that also hosts another site that uses HTTPS.

This confuses Lighthouse (the engine that runs Page Speed Insights (PSI)) when used in Headless mode - which is how PSI works. (headless means no GUI effectively)

What happens is it tries to connect via HTTPS - the server says there is a certificate for that server (as certificate lookup is by server IP address) but it doesn't reconcile the fact that the SSL certificate is for another website and at this point fails as it tries to load the site over HTTPS when the site can only load via HTTP.

As it is a good idea to use HTTPS I would suggest installing a SSL certificate on your server and serving the site via HTTPS only.

If you want to test the site as is you can open Google Chrome, Go to Settings > More Tools > Developer Tools > Audits tab.

The audits tab uses the same engine (Lighthouse) as PSI uses so will give similar results.